# Why can't I post a question anymore after getting a several downvotes?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, closed-questions

When I try to ask a question on SO, but my question is too obvious, the question gets closed. After that, I tried to ask a question again, but I couldn't post it. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have [asked a lot of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355005/klox) that get answered.

If a question gets closed, read the reason by it is closed. If it is a duplicate, it is because it has already been asked. After it is closed you should get some links to possible duplicates, and you'll find your answer there.

Comment: how to restore this to normal? so I can ask again?

Comment: @klox I believe there is a time period before you can ask a question again.

Comment: had two days I could not ask, perhaps I should be patient

Answer (score 4):

You may want to refer to this

[Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system)